# Prove $\det(A+B)=\det(B)$ implies that $A = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

first time here.
I tried my best to translate the question :

Show that the only matrix $A$ of size $n\times n$ that verify $\det(A+B)=\det(B)$, for any $n\times n$ matrix $B$, is the null matrix (the matrix full of zero, here of size n).

I thought about using the formula $\det(A)$ that uses matrices of size $(n-1)$:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiPym.png)

But can't find to make it work.
Any ideas ? I don't need a full proof, only the start of it so I can try myself because i'm stuck

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112694/discussion-on-question-by-oezlmaz-prove-detab-detb-implies-that-a-0).

Comment: If $B\neq 0$ is singular, the claim is false, because  then we can take $A=-B$

Answer (score 5):

HINT: Let $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $v \neq 0$. Then the set $\{v\}$ can be extended to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Use this fact to prove, by contradiction, that $A$ can't have a non zero column.

Comment: I think that your last sentence is actually a good enough hint by itself! If the $i$th column of $A$ is a nonzero column vector $c$ and $j \neq i$, then $A$ has the same determinant as $A+B$ where $B$ is the matrix with $j$th column $c$ and zeros elsewhere.

Comment: @MikeF I suspect this would only lead to $\det(A)=0$. However it is certainly a good starting point.

Comment: Whoops, yes you're right about that.

Answer (score 1):

Write $A = PJ_rQ$ where $P,Q$ are invertible and $J_r$ is the diagonal matrix with $r$ "$1$"s and $n-r$ "$0$"s on the diagonal (so $r$ is the rank of $A$). Then with $B=-PQ$, you have $\det(B) \neq 0$ and
$$\det(A+B)= \det(P)\det(J_r - I_n) \det(Q)$$

which is $\neq 0$ iff $r=0$. So $A$ has rank $0$, i.e. $A = 0$.